# Showing that $L$ is recognizable

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

> Let $L$ be the language of all the words with the shape $<M_1,M_2,w>$ such that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are turing muchines that both accepts the word $w$.
>
> Show that $L$ is recognizable

I thought to build a new machine $M_3$ such that $M_3$ will accept $L$, any ideas how can I build such a machine?

Comment: This cannot possibly be decidable. It would be almost trivial to use an $L$-decider to decide the halting problem, for example

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry, I meant recognizable

Comment: Okay, now the conclusion looks right -- roughly, if you know how to build a universal machine, you can have that machine first simulate $M_1$ on $w$ and then simulate $M_2$ on $w$. Exactly how you would _prove_ there is a machine that does that depends _a lot_ of which tools for constructing Turing machines you already have available. Constructing it state by state and proving its correctness from scratch would be a Herculean task, so you have to look for which general techniques to _combine_ existing computable functions you have ready to exploit in your proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible construction for $M_3$ would be:

$M_3= \;$On input $<M_1, M_2, w>$
$\quad\quad\quad\quad$ simulate $M_1$ on $w$
$\quad\quad\quad\quad$ simulate $M_2$ on $w$
$\quad\quad\quad\quad$ if both $M_1$ and $M_2$ accept $w$
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ accept
$\quad\quad\quad\quad$ else
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ reject

$M_3$ is not a decider because if either $M_1$ or $M_2$ loops, then $M_3$ will loop